# recyclerView Add & Delete

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an Android project, where I have set up a recyclerView for a CardView.

Here I have a 3 dot image, which have included a menu, where I can add or delete an item of the recyclerView. It looks like this:

[image]

For some reason, when I delete an item, and thereafter add items. Then sometimes the deleted item shows up. When I change a title to let's say "Room 1", and I delete it, then it will show up again, when I add new items. Anyone knows why this happens. Why won't it DELETE the item?

Thanks in advance!

*** CODE HERE ***

Recycler Adapter

```
public class lokationRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<lokationRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

List<String> cardList;
String test;

SensorOversigtFragment sensorOversigtFragment;

public interface listListener {
    void onAddListener( List<String> cardList, int position);
}

public lokationRecyclerAdapter(List<String> cardList) {
    this.cardList = cardList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from( viewGroup.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.lokationcardview, viewGroup, false );
    return new RecyclerViewHolder( view );
}

public void addItem() {
    cardList.add( new String() );
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void deleteItem(int position) {
    cardList.remove( position );
    notifyItemRemoved( position );
    notifyItemRangeChanged( position, cardList.size() );

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int position) {
    recyclerViewHolder.cardView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.ic_circleshape );
    listListener.onAddListener(cardList.get( position ), position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cardList.size();
}

class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public int nummer;
    private CardView cardView;
    private Button menuButton;
    private TextView lokationsName;

    public void alertDialog(View itemView) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder( itemView.getContext() );

        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder( itemView.getContext() );
        builder.setCancelable( true );
        builder.setTitle( "Tilføj eller ændre navnet på lokation" );
        builder.setMessage( "Hold styr på dine sensorer ved at oprette lokationer i form af eksempelvis lokaler." );

        final EditText input = new EditText( itemView.getContext() );
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
        input.setMaxLines( 1 );
        input.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
        input.setLayoutParams( lp );
        builder.setView( input );

        builder.setPositiveButton( "Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                test = input.getText().toString();
                lokationsName.setText( test );
            }
        } );

        builder.setNegativeButton( "Nej", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        } );

        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }

    public RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super( itemView );

        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.lokationcard_view );
        menuButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.menuButton );
        lokationsName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.lokationsName );

        itemView.setOnClickListener( this );

        menuButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu( itemView.getContext(), menuButton );
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.lokationpopmenu, popupMenu.getMenu() );

                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener( new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {

                            case R.id.changeLokation:
                                System.out.println( "GET ADAPTER POSITION: " + getAdapterPosition() );
                                alertDialog( itemView );
                                break;

                            case R.id.addCardView:
                                String lokation = lokationsName.getText().toString();
                                System.out.println("LOKATIONS NAME: " + lokation );
                                if(lokation.equals( "TILFØJ LOKATION" )) {
                                   Toast.makeText( itemView.getContext(), "Du skal ændre navnet på lokation først!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                } else {
                                    addItem();
                                }
                                break;

                            case R.id.deleteCardView:
                                if (cardList.size() > 1) {
                                    deleteItem( getAdapterPosition() );
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText( itemView.getContext(), "Du kan ikke slette den sidste CardView", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                }
                                break;

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                } );
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        } );

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        nummer = getAdapterPosition();
        Intent intent = new Intent( itemView.getContext(), gridTabelActivity.class );
        Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation( v.getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left ).toBundle();
        itemView.getContext().startActivity( intent, bundle );
    }



 }

}
```

Fragment initializing recyclerView

```
public class SensorOversigtFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();

public SensorOversigtFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public void onAddListener(List<String> cardList, int position) {
    test = cardList;
    cardList.add( new String() );
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.lokationcardlist, container, false );

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById( R.id.lokationrecycler_view );

    test.add( "test" );

    adapter = new lokationRecyclerAdapter( test );
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );
    recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( this.getActivity() );
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager( linearLayoutManager );

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have API call for your list item, yes then deleted item is coming back again from API (And that's functional issue).

Comment: No, it's not. It's receiving an Arraylist from a Fragment. I'm attaching the code. You can find it in my question

Comment: @Yas this happens because you're deleting it from list passed to Adapter. it will be deleted for that time, but when you reload adapter again and pass it a list.  it shows new list.

Comment: @Yas Are you updating the ArrayList after deleting the item?

Comment: oh, why haven't I thought about that.... Can you help me with updating the list in SensorOversigtFragment? How do I update it? Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an interface for adding and should listen to that interface from the fragment and only from there you should add or delete items

```
           makerInterface.onAddListener(cardList.get(position),position);
```

and this should go inside onBindViewHolder

TeamMakerInterface.java

```
public interface TeamMakerInterface {

    void onAddListener( List<String> cardList,int position);

}
```

Instead of Adding and deleting it inside do that in the fragment itself

```
    @Override
    public void onAddListener( List<String> cardList,int position) {
       cardList.add( new String() );
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ABr! Unfortunately, I have no real experience with interfaces. I have added an interface called onAddListener, inside the Adapter, but I have trouble understanding how I receive data through the listener? 

I have uploaded the code with interface in fragment!

Comment: Actually the onAddListener is  a method inside interface which is used to communicate to the fragment

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's much appreciated! But when that's said, how am i supposed to make this work, when my menu is in recyclerView. Can't I somehow just delete from recyclerView and then update in the fragment? Or is that stupid?

Comment: did you run and get anything? please override the listener method inside fragment